# New to Android development- what does this line of XML mean?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to programming and trying to learn android development with android studio. I updated Java and tried to update android SDK when it crashed. I finally got the Android SDK update fixed but now I have this error in an app I was working on. It's in the `activity_main.xml` file
The error says "cannot resolve this symbol: `MainActivity.java`"

Here's the line where the error shows up.

```
 tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity.java"
```

`MainActivity.java` is red. I feel like it's directory tree issue, but I can't tell what the program wants so I can fix it.

Comment: Do you have a MainActivity.java in the package com.example.android.justjava?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.java` at the end, and make sure that `MainActivity.java` exists inside the package `com.example.android.justjava`.

What is the purpose of writing that line?

> **tools:context**
>
> This attribute is typically set on the root element in a layout XML
>   file, and records which activity the layout is associated with (at
>   designtime, since obviously a layout can be used by more than one
>   layout). This will for example be used by the layout editor to guess a
>   default theme, since themes are defined in the Manifest and are
>   associated with activities, not layouts.

Source: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes

Comment: That line also only used by the IDE, it isn't needed by the app itself

Comment: That fixed it. Awesome. I really appreciate it, I've been stuck all day. I didn't write that line of code. It was created in studio when I started the project.